# Truly statistical task

Tags: probability, probability-calculus

I have a specific task in programming but I am curious about how long it will take to complete.

I have an array "A" with 1000 unique numbers inside.

For each iteration I am copying 30 randomly picked numbers from array "A" to array "B".

Duplicate numbers(which already exists in array "B") are not copied

Question is: how many iterations do I need to claim with a **certain probability**, that all numbers are copied from "A" to "B"

Thanks

Comment: do you pick 30 numbers randomly?

Comment: yes, sorry I will add it to the question

Comment: is this a home work? you better show what you've done so far to solve the problem. it's an easy quiz type of question.

Comment: No it's not a homework, that is why I have no idea of where to start to solve it. I have only conditions :)

Comment: I simplified the conditions, in reality each iteration takes about 2 minutes for now. I want to know how long it will take or how much I should decrease iteration duration

Comment: In the duplicate question, simply change "stickers" to "numbers," "424" to "1000," and "5" to "30".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to answer your question is to answer a similar question: what is the probability that any given number in A was not picked after $N$ iterations?

The answer to this question is: $P=(1-\frac{30}{1000})^N$

Then the answer to your original question is $\frac{\ln (1-p)}{\ln(1-\frac{30}{1000})}$, where $p=1-P$ is your **certain probability**.

Also, a word **certain** usually refers to probability 100% or 1. I'm assuming that you use this word in its different meaning, i.e. "specific but not explicitly named or stated".

Comment: This solution is not correct.  For a correct solution, with references, please see the duplicate.